# Exit status 223 (out of memory) when pushing to IBM Cloud

Tags: out-of-memory, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am running into trouble deploying apps from my local dev environment. My `cf push` always fails with a `Exit status 223 (out of memory)` error (irrespective of the app).

I am certain both my IBM Cloud Org and my local environment have sufficient space to work with.

Here is the stack trace:

```html
REQUEST: [2018-02-14T09:02:04-05:00]
GET /v2/apps/7426064e-0d6c-469e-8d6d-01e47728be01 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.ng.bluemix.net
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: go-cli 6.32.0+0191c33d9.2017-09-26 / darwin


  10% building modules 8/17 modules 9 active ...node_modules/fbjs/lib/containsNode.js   
 89% additionsets processing                                      Hash: 9d08b2614d7a87cb99ad              
       Version: webpack 2.7.0
       js/bundle.9d08b2614d7a87cb99ad.js     297 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
       js/bundle.9d08b2614d7a87cb99ad.js.map     466 kB       0  [emitted]         main
       index.html  304 bytes          [emitted]
       [0] ./~/react/index.js 190 bytes {0} [built]
       [4] ./client/app/App.jsx 858 bytes {0} [built]
       [5] ./~/react-dom/index.js 1.36 kB {0} [built]
       [6] ./client/default.scss 1.03 kB {0} [built]
       [8] ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./client/default.scss 193 kB {0} [built]
       [9] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 2.26 kB {0} [built]
       [12] ./~/fbjs/lib/containsNode.js 923 bytes {0} [built]
       Time: 73789ms
       Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
       [7] ./client/index.jsx 222 bytes {0} [built]
       [10] ./~/fbjs/lib/EventListener.js 2.25 kB {0} [built]
       [11] ./~/fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment.js 935 bytes {0} [built]
       [13] ./~/fbjs/lib/focusNode.js 578 bytes {0} [built]
       [14] ./~/fbjs/lib/getActiveElement.js 912 bytes {0} [built]
       [18] ./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js 92.7 kB {0} [built]
       [19] ./~/react/cjs/react.production.min.js 5.41 kB {0} [built]
       [20] ./~/style-loader/addStyles.js 6.91 kB {0} [built]
       + 6 hidden modules
       Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
       [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
       [1] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./client/index.html 590 bytes {0} [built]
       [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
       [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
-----> Build failed

Failed to compile droplet: Failed to compile droplet: exit status 137
Exit status 223 (out of memory)
Staging failed: STG: Exited with status 223 (out of memory)
Stopping instance 0ee88ef2-8cd4-4096-9c3c-dee1870cf758
Destroying container
Successfully destroyed container
```

Has anyone run into this issue? Does anyone have any ideas on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you could try:

- Restarting the app
- Re-installing npm packages (npm install)
- Updating node, npm versions
- Increasing the app space on IBM Cloud
- Reduce the overall memory used by the app
- Looking for possible memory leaks
- Possible issues with packages (webpack etc)

**Here's what worked for me**:

In my NodeJS package.json, I added:

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">= 7.0.0",
  "npm": ">= 4.2.0"
}
```

I believe the issue was with IBM Cloud's default npm version, versus the version I was using in my local environment. Once I specified the version in my package.json, IBM Cloud was able to complete the build and deploy.

If people have a better understanding of what the error was and why this solution worked, please share.

Comment: I believe you can accept your own answer.  You should do that if that was the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your application's available memory.
and check wether your application produces any memory leak.

The quickest thing to try is :

You can increase memory allocation for your app.

- Login to the Cloud's Dashboard.
- Select your app and increase MEMORY QUOTA.
- This will restart the app.
- Try pushing again.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that staging has failed because the process used up too much memory.  In short, whatever is running is exceeding the memory limit for the staging container.

```
Failed to compile droplet: Failed to compile droplet: exit status 137
Exit status 223 (out of memory)
Staging failed: STG: Exited with status 223 (out of memory)
```

You've got three options for working around this.

1. Cloud Foundry will set the memory limit for the staging container to either an operator defined value or the size of the memory limit you picked for your app, whichever one is larger.  I can't say what the operator defined limit is for your platform, but you can probably work around this by simply setting a larger memory limit.  Just try pushing again with larger values until it succeeds.  Then after the push is successful, you can `cf scale -m` and lower the memory limit back down to what you need for runtime.
2. The other option would be to take a look at your build scripts or whatever runs to stage your application, and work to reduce the memory it requires.  Making it consume less memory should also resolve this issue.
3. Lastly, you can stage your app locally.  To do this you would run your build scripts on your local machine and then push the final product.  You can't skip the staging process altogether, but if things are already prepared to run then staging usually becomes a no-op.

Hope that helps!